tikzpicture exceeds table cells with multirow
I'm using multirow together with tikz pictures and the result is suprising (at least to me). I reduced the code to:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
        \hline
        \multirow{2}{*}{
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \fill[red, fill opacity = 0.2] (0, 0) rectangle (5, 5);
            \end{tikzpicture}
        }
        &
        {
            \begin{tabular}{@{}|l|l|@{}}
                \hline
                Foo & bar \\
                \hline
                Foo & bar \\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
        }
        \\
        \cline{2-2}
        &
        a
        \\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|@{}c@{}|}
        {
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \fill[red, fill opacity = 0.2] (0, 0) rectangle (10, 5);
            \end{tikzpicture}
        }
        \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}

This produces , where the top-left cell exceeds the cell boundaries (or more precisely where the cell boundary is not sized accordingly). What am I doing wrong?

I don't think multirow figures out how tall or whatever the cell should be. you have to make sure sufficient space is left by specifying the number of rows. if you put something which is as tall as 5 rows but only allow 1, it won't fit. that's just how it works. I'm not sure if that's the bit you find unexpected or something else, though ...

Well, I did expect automatic sizing, hence my confusion. But thanks for clearing that up :)

You could use tabularray:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tblr}{
        colspec={cc},
        hlines, vlines,
        vspan=even,
        abovesep=6pt
        }
        \SetCell[r=2]{}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \fill[red, fill opacity = 0.2] (0, 0) rectangle (5, 5);
            \end{tikzpicture}
        &
            \begin{tabular}{@{}|l|l|@{}}
                \hline
                Foo & bar \\
                \hline
                Foo & bar \\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \\
        &
        a
        \\
        \SetCell[c=2]{}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \fill[red, fill opacity = 0.2] (0, 0) rectangle (10, 5);
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}


